# amazon s3 PutObjectAsync Cannot access a closed stream

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to amazon s3 but got error `Cannot Access a closed stream` in `await client.PutObjectAsync(request);`

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    await sWriter.WriteAsync(commandWithMetadata.SerializeToString());
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    var fileName = GetFileName(command);

                    var request = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = BucketName,
                        Key = fileName,
                        InputStream = stream
                    };
                    await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is `AutoCloseStream` property on request which by default is true and amazon lib is closing the stream automatically